# Sort list of dicts by list index of dictionary

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, dictionary

I have a list of dicts, where the dict has a list itself. How can I sort using factors index?

For example sort descending the list by `factors[0]`

```
[{'score': '2.0', 'id': 686, 'factors': [2.0, 2.25, 2.75, 1.5, 2.25]}, {'score': '1.9', 'id': 863, 'factors': [1.5, 3.0, 1.5, 2.5, 1.5]}, {'score': '2.0', 'id': 55, 'factors': [1.5, 3.0, 2.5, 1.5, 1.5]}, {'score': '1.9', 'id': 756, 'factors': [1.25, 2.25, 2.5, 2.0, 1.75]}]
```

Comment: sort(dd, key=lambda x: x['factors'][0])

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I sort a list of dictionaries by a value of the dictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72899/how-do-i-sort-a-list-of-dictionaries-by-a-value-of-the-dictionary)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially what you need to do is use `sorted`. However this `factors[0]` seems a bit arbitrary, perhaps you want to sort the list first and then sort by its first value?

However this exmple get the jobs done. Keep in mind it won't be usable for ties, so you might want to add a second sorting key:

```
sort = sorted(ex, key=lambda x: x['factors'][0])
sort
```

Output:

```
[{'factors': [1.25, 2.25, 2.5, 2.0, 1.75], 'id': 756, 'score': '1.9'},
 {'factors': [1.5, 3.0, 1.5, 2.5, 1.5], 'id': 863, 'score': '1.9'}, #Tied values
 {'factors': [1.5, 3.0, 2.5, 1.5, 1.5], 'id': 55, 'score': '2.0'}, #Tied values
 {'factors': [2.0, 2.25, 2.75, 1.5, 2.25], 'id': 686, 'score': '2.0'}]
```

Example of sorting by `factors[0]` followed by `id` for tied values. Please note how the order is the other way around, first you sort by id (inner sort) and then factors in the code (outer sort):

```
sort = sorted(sorted(ex,key=lambda x: x['id']),key=lambda x: x['factors'][0])
sort
```

Output:

```
[{'factors': [1.25, 2.25, 2.5, 2.0, 1.75], 'id': 756, 'score': '1.9'},
 {'factors': [1.5, 3.0, 2.5, 1.5, 1.5], 'id': 55, 'score': '2.0'},
 {'factors': [1.5, 3.0, 1.5, 2.5, 1.5], 'id': 863, 'score': '1.9'},
 {'factors': [2.0, 2.25, 2.75, 1.5, 2.25], 'id': 686, 'score': '2.0'}]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass it as a key

```
my_list=[{'score': '2.0', 'id': 686, 'factors': [2.0, 2.25, 2.75, 1.5, 2.25]}, {'score': '1.9', 'id': 863, 'factors': [1.5, 3.0, 1.5, 2.5, 1.5]}, {'score': '2.0', 'id': 55, 'factors': [1.5, 3.0, 2.5, 1.5, 1.5]}, {'score': '1.9', 'id': 756, 'factors': [1.25, 2.25, 2.5, 2.0, 1.75]}]
sorted(my_list, key=lambda x: x['factors'][0])
```

Output:

```
[{'score': '1.9', 'id': 756, 'factors': [1.25, 2.25, 2.5, 2.0, 1.75]},
 {'score': '1.9', 'id': 863, 'factors': [1.5, 3.0, 1.5, 2.5, 1.5]},
 {'score': '2.0', 'id': 55, 'factors': [1.5, 3.0, 2.5, 1.5, 1.5]},
 {'score': '2.0', 'id': 686, 'factors': [2.0, 2.25, 2.75, 1.5, 2.25]}]
```